# Frequent Compaction of OpsCenter.rollup_state on all the nodes consuming CPU cycles

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I am using Datastax Cassandra 4.8.16. With cluster of 8 DC and 5 nodes on each DC on VM's. For last couple of weeks we observed below performance issue

1) Increase drop count on VM's.

[image]

2) LOCAL_QUORUM for some write operation not achieved.

3) Frequent Compaction of **OpsCenter.rollup_state** and **system.hints** are visible in Opscenter.

Appreciate any help finding the root cause for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presence of dropped mutations means that cluster is heavily overloaded.  It could be increase of the main load, so it + load from OpsCenter, overloaded system - you need to look into statistics about number of requests, latencies, etc. per nodes and per tables, to see where increase happened. Please also check the I/O statistics on machines (for example, with `iostat`) - sizes of the queues, read/write latencies, etc.

Also it's recommended to use a dedicated OpsCenter cluster to store metrics - it could be smaller size, and doesn't require an additional license for DSE.  How it said in the [OpsCenter's documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.1/opsc/configure/opscStoringCollectionDataDifferentCluster_t.html):

> **Important**: In production environments, DataStax strongly recommends storing data in a separate DataStax Enterprise cluster.

Regarding VMs - usually it's not really recommended setup, but heavily depends on what kind of underlying hardware - number of CPUs, RAM, disk system.

Comment: How can I stop frequent compaction of Opscenter.rollup_state? I see 50% of cluster node performing compaction on this table.

Comment: It looks like that you have too much data in it. Consider decreasing the time to leave for 1 minute tables, and maybe excluding some keyspaces from data collection - both topics are described in documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.1/opsc/configure/opscControllingDataCollection_c.html